# Optimal strategy in one-player game

Tags: probability

> You are playing a one-player game with two opaque boxes. At each turn,
> you can choose to either "place" or "take". "Place" places $1 from a
> third party into one box randomly. "Take" empties out one box randomly
> and that money is yours. This game consists of 100 turns where you
> must either place or take. Assuming optimal play, what is the expected
> payoff of this game? Note that you do not know how much money you have
> taken until the end of the game.

It is obvious that the more you take, the less you can earn, for example if you place at turn $1$ and then keep taking, the expected payoff is $0.5$. I thought of doing the opposite and keep placing until the $100$th turn where we have already placed $99\$$. Let $X_n$ denote the amount in box $1$ at the $n$th turn. $X_n$ follows a binomial distribution Bin($n,0.5$). For box $2$, its amount $Y_n$ is $n-X_n$ which is also Bin($n,0.5$). Hence, after the $99th$ "place", there is on average $49.5\$$ in each box which you take at the $100$th turn meaning the expected payoff is $49.5\$$. Is this right ? Is there a better strategy I am not thinking of ?

Comment: I just realized that I could "take" many times after "places" for example, placing 98 times and taking twice I could maybe win whats in both boxes

Comment: Try to prove that for any sequence of $x$ 'places' and $y$ 'takes' in some order, the strategy where all takes occur last and all places occur first is more efficient.  The question then boils down to how many 'takes' to perform and not a question of when to do them.

Comment: Place N times in a row,  then take repeatedly. Find optimal   N.

Comment: I wonder if there's a clever way to leverage the [odds algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_algorithm) for this.

Comment: @Kilkik: Going $98/2$ still leaves you a $3/4$ chance of not taking both boxes, so you'd win slightly less than $75$ on average.

Comment: Please provide a reference for the original source of the problem (or any material originally written by others): https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you place for $N$ consecutive rounds and then take for the last $100-N$.

You will then collect $N$, unless you are unlucky enough to take from the same box each time.  In the latter case, you'd expect to get only $\frac N2$.

Thus, as a function of $N$ your expected gain is $$N\times \left(1-\frac 1{2^{100-N}}\right)$$

It is easily verified that this numerically matches (well, closely anyway) the simulation results obtained by @JMoravitz above and confirms that $N=94$ is optimal.  For that $N$ I get an expected value of $92.53125$, for example.

Comment: In fact, I got the same result!

Answer (score 0):

I do not as of yet see a clean way to approach with pen-and-paper, but I am finding from simulation that $94$ places and $6$ takes appears to be optimal.

Dirty javascript code for simulation.  100000 simulations for each strategy.

```
results=[];
totalNumber=100;
for(numberOfPlacings=0; numberOfPlacings<100; numberOfPlacings++){
   winnings=0;
   for(simNumber=0;simNumber<100000;simNumber++){
      boxes=[0,0];
      for(round=0;round<totalNumber;round++){
          if(round<numberOfPlacings){
              boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*2)]+=1
          }
          else{
              chosenBox = Math.floor(Math.random()*2); 
              winnings+=boxes[chosenBox];
              boxes[chosenBox]=0
          }
      }
  };
  results.push(winnings/100000)
}
```

Having simulated each option for the number of times to perform places vs takes, we end up with very slightly less than the total amount of money placed in each case up to the $90$'s where it becomes more interesting.

$\begin{array}{c|c}90&91&92&93&94\\89.92338&90.83088&91.64815&92.27359&92.51002\\\hline95&96&97&98&99\\91.99924&90.03692&84.84217&73.57936&49.50047\end{array}$

As a sanity check, this matches with what we expected for $99$ being an expected value of precisely $49.5$ and for $98$ being a value of precisely $49+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 49=73.5$, the numbers being off a small amount due to acceptable randomness.

Repeating the test specifically only for the numbers $90$ to $99$ and increasing the number of simulations to five million, this time the numbers were

$\begin{array}{c|c}90&91&92&93&94\\89.910801&90.8219232&91.6443782&92.2768562&92.5352562\\\hline95&96&97&98&99\\92.033191&89.9918214&84.8678906&73.503462&49.4991134\end{array}$

Comment: I think I have a solution that is doable using pencil and paper--please see my answer. (Your comments are welcome!)

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR: Skip to the end for examples!**

Given that we are allowed $N>0$ turns total (in our case $N=100$), we want to choose "place" for $(N-n)$ turns, followed by choosing "take" for the remaining $n$ turns.  (We should prove that, whenever we choose "take" on $n$ turns, it is best if those $n$ turns are at the end. One idea might be: given any arrangement $A$ of $n$ "take" moves and $(N-n)$ "place" moves, let $Z$ be the arrangement of $(N-n)$ "place" moves at the beginning followed by $n$ "take" moves at the end.  You verify that, for every sequence of coin flips, both for the "takes" and the "places", every dollar won under $A$ would still be won under $Z$. There's a bit of work to be done, but I think this should work.)

Then the goal is just to find the optimal value of $n$.

The total money available will be $(N-n)$.  By the Law of Total Expectation, our expected winnings will be
$$
\begin{align*}
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,P({\text{Box 1 is taken } n \text{ times in a row}})\cdot E({\text{money in box 1}})\\ 
&+ P({\text{Box 2 is taken } n \text{ times in a row}})\cdot E({\text{money in box 2}})\\ 
&+ P({\text{each box is taken at least once}})\cdot (N-n). 
\end{align*}
$$

This is
$$
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= 
\frac{1}{2^n}\left( \frac{1}{2}(N-n) \right) + \frac{1}{2^n}\left( \frac{1}{2}(N-n) \right) + \left(1 - \frac{2}{2^n}\right)(N-n)\\
&= 
(N-n) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right).
\end{align*}
$$

So, for a fixed $N$, we want to find the $n$ that maximizes $f(n) = (N-n)(1 - 2^{-n})$.  (As a check, we note that $f(0) = 0 = f(N)$, while $f(n) > 0$ when $0 < n < N$.)

Take the derivative and set it equal to $0$:
$$
0 = f'(n) = (-1)(1 - 2^{-n}) + (N-n) (2^{-n}\ln 2).
$$
Equivalently,
$$
\begin{align*}
2^n - 1 &= (N-n)\ln 2\\
2^n + n\ln 2 &= 1 + N\ln 2.
\end{align*}
$$
This equation has exactly one solution $n\in (0,N)$ (why?).  Of course this unique solution is probably not an integer, but the optimal choice will be given by either the floor or the ceiling of this value.  (Notice also that the real-number solution $n$ will always increase as $N$ increases.)

For $N=100$ we get that the optimal choice is either $n=6$ or $n=7$ (since $2^6 + 6\ln 2 < 1 + 100\ln 2$, while $2^7 + 7\ln 2 > 1 + 100\ln 2$).  Of these two choices, we find that
$$f(6) = (100-6)\left(1 - \frac{1}{64}\right) = 92.53125
$$
while
$$
f(7) = (100-7) \left(1- \frac{1}{128}\right) = 92.2734375.
$$
So $n=6$ is better; we should "place" for $94$ turns, and then "take" for the remaining $6$ turns.

If $N=1000$ instead, the optimal choice is $n=9$.  If $N$ is $1$ million then the optimal choice is $n=19$, with an expected value of about $999979.0926876$.

Clearly the optimal $n$ grows fairly slowly with $N$; let $F(N)$ denote the optimal choice of $n$ for $N$ total turns (or, if there are multiple choices of $n$ which are optimal, then let $F(N)$ be the smallest such $n$). Then it seems $F$ is constant for long periods at a time. We might like to know when it happens that the value of $F(N)$ increases, meaning that $F(N+1)>F(N)$. This happens when the following are true for some $n$:

$$
(N-n) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \geq (N-(n+1)) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right)
$$
and
$$
((N+1)-n) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} \right) < ((N+1)-(n+1)) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right).
$$

The first inequality is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align*}
(N-n) \left( 2^{n+1} - 2 \right) &\geq (N-(n+1)) \left( 2^{n+1} - 1 \right)\\
(N-n) (2^{n+1}-1) - (N-n) &\geq (N-n) (2^{n+1}-1) - (2^{n+1} - 1)
\end{align*}
$$
which reduces to
$$
N \leq 2^{n+1} + n - 1.
$$
Meanwhile the other inequality reduces to
$$
N > 2^{n+1} + n - 2.
$$
So $F(N+1) > F(N)$ when
$$
2^{n+1} + n - 2 < N \leq 2^{n+1} + n - 1,
$$
which (since $N$ is an integer) means
$$
N = 2^{n+1} + n - 1.
$$
In other words $N+1 = 2^{n+1} + (n+1) - 1$.  This tells us that $F$ is constant on intervals $J_i = [a_i, b_{i})\cap\mathbb{Z}$, where the left-hand endpoints $a_i$ are exactly $2^{i} + i - 1$.

We expect that $F(N+1)-F(N)$ is always either $0$ or $1$. To verify this, we prove that, if $$(N-n)(1 - 2^{-n}) \geq (N- (n+1))(1 - 2^{-(n+1)}),$$ then $$((N+1) - (n+1)) (1 - 2^{-(n+1)}) \geq ((N+1) - (n+2))(1 - 2^{-(n+2)}).$$   For, by hypothesis
$$
\frac{(N+1)-(n+2)}{(N+1)-(n+1)} = \frac{N-(n+1)}{N-n}\leq \frac{1-2^{-n}}{1-2^{-(n+1)}},
$$
and we can show that this last fraction is less than or equal to $\frac{1-2^{-(n+1)}}{1-2^{-(n+2)}}$.  Therefore $F$ increases by exactly $1$ at each "jump". Consequently (by induction on $n$),
$$
\begin{align*}
F(N) = n &\Longleftrightarrow 2^{n} + n - 1 \leq N < 2^{n+1} + (n+1) - 1\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \log_2(2^n + n - 1) \leq \log_2(N) < \log_2(2^{n+1} + (n+1) - 1)\\
&\Longrightarrow n \leq \left\lfloor\log_2(N)\right\rfloor \leq n+1.
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore
$$
F(N) \leq \left\lfloor \log_2(N)\right\rfloor \leq F(N) + 1.
$$

Equivalently,
$$
\left\lfloor \log_2(N)\right\rfloor  - 1 \leq F(N) \leq \left\lfloor \log_2(N)\right\rfloor.
$$

So, for each $N$, you can find the optimal $n$ by evaluating $f$ at just two values: $\left\lfloor\log_2(N)\right\rfloor$, and $\left(\left\lfloor\log_2(N)\right\rfloor - 1\right)$.

Or if you prefer, let $L = \left\lfloor\log_2(N)\right\rfloor$, and then check whether $2^L + L - 1 \leq N < 2^{L+1} + (L+1) - 1$.  If so, $F(N) = L$; otherwise, $F(N) = L-1$.  In fact, the right-hand inequality is always true, so we really just need to check whether
$$
2^L + L - 1 \leq N.
$$

By the way, calculating $L = \left\lfloor \log_2(N)\right\rfloor$ is not too hard; write $N$ in binary and count the digits, then subtract $1$. And then $2^L$ (in binary) is also easy: take $N$, keep its initial $1$, and change all its other bits to $0$.  So it would be convenient to work in base-$2$ for this problem.

**Example:** Suppose we are allowed $N=100$ turns, as in the OP, so in binary $N=1{,}100{,}100_2$. Then $L = \left\lfloor \log_2(N)\right\rfloor = 6=110_2$, and $2^L = 1{,}000{,}000_2$.  Also $L-1 = 101_2 = 5$, so
$$
2^L + L - 1 = 1{,}000{,}101_2 \leq 1{,}100{,}100_2 = N.
$$
Therefore it is optimal to choose $n = L = 110_2 = 6$.  (Choose "place" $100-6=94$ times, then choose "take" for the remaining $6$ turns.)

**Example:** Suppose $N=259$, so in binary $N = 100{,}000{,}011_2$.  Then $L = 8 = 1000_2$, and $2^L = 100{,}000{,}000_2$. Also $L-1 = 111_2 = 7$, so
$$
2^L + L - 1 = 100{,}000{,}111_2 > 100{,}000{,}011_2 = N.
$$
Therefore it is optimal to choose $n = L-1 = 111_2 = 7$.  (Choose "place" $259-7=252$ times, then choose "take" for the remaining $7$ turns.)